# Gmail Authentication Failure from smtpmail (emacs + mu4e)

Tags: smtp, gmail, mu4e

I'm facing a similar problem to the one described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1479809/smtpmail-send-it-authentication-failed-in-response-to-auth-plain-emacs-mu4e). However, the error I receive when I try to send a email from mu4e is:

> smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required

Here is my configuration section in the `config.el` file of Doom Emacs  (following [this post by djcb](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Gmail-configuration.html)):

```
(require 'smtpmail)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
   starttls-use-gnutls t
   smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
   smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
;;   smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
   smtpmail-smtp-user "pcremades@fcen.uncu.edu.ar"
   smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

I read [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmtpAuth) that the variable `smtpmail-auth-credentials` is no longer used, and that `.authinfo` is searched automatically. So I placed my authentication info in `.authinfo.gpg`. The content of the file is:

> machine smtp.gmail.com login myuser@server password "app-pass" port 587

where app-pass is the 16 character app specific password that I generated through Gmail 2FA settings.

I know that smtpmail is accessing the `.authinfo.gpg` file because I'm asked for the password to decrypt the file. However, I always end up receiving the error message above.

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [emacs.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).